History of the migration of ERA from AMS to AIMS in 2007
From what I can read on their websites, the journal Electronic Research Announcements changed publisher from the very reputable AMS (American Mathematical Society) to the much less known AIMS (American Institute of Mathematical Sciences) in 2007, and changed name to Electronic Research Announcements in Mathematical Sciences and later Electronic Research Archive.
At the same time, apparently several editors left.
I am curious as to how and why this migration took place. The last volume before the migration does not seem to include an editorial or announcement of the migration, and my limited Googling skills cannot find one. Does anyone have more information on it, or maybe even a first-hand account?

Tim Gowers says a little bit about this in his blog post about the journal Mathematics Research Reports (which was founded by a group of editors who resigned from ERA around 2019):

[Electronic Research Announcements] never published all that many papers, and in 2007, I think for that reason (but don’t remember for sure), the AMS decided to discontinue it. But Svetlana Katok had put a lot into the journal and managed to find another publisher, the American Institute of Mathematical Sciences, and the editorial board agreed to continue serving. The name of the journal was changed to Electronic Research Announcements in the Mathematical Sciences, and its abbreviation was slightly abbreviated from ERA-AMS to ERA-MS.


Thanks! This is very useful and answers my question perfectly.
